# Windows Phone 7/WPF - Sharing a codebase

Tags: wpf, winforms, windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, interop

I've developed Windows Mobile apps in the past and have always found that when trying to share a codebase with Windows (Winforms/WPF) apps, generally things get very difficult. Has this changed with Windows Phone 7? It would be great to add a WP7 app to a solution containing  a WPF app and ASP.NET site and have everything share the same code base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the Portable Library Tools CTP [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981/)

It's a Visual Studio add-in that enables you to create libraries that run on a variety of .NET platforms without recompilation.

Comment: +1 for the Portable Library Tools (and I didn't know they'd made CTP already!). Also worth looking at Mix in a week's time - might be another release then?

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the Portable Library Tools mentioned by Steve Chadbourne handy for sharing code and your project layout. However you will find some capability differences from Silverlight Mobile, Silverlight desktop and WPF.

Unfortunately nothing can be totally compatible because the various platforms are different. A phone can't include the entire .NET framework.

You'll find it hit or miss. While WPF, Silverlight and Silverlight mobile share many classes and API's, you'll find things like sockets missing on Windows Phone 7 where you had sockets in the .NET Compact Framework v1 to v3.5.