# How to organize Windows and Windows Phone projects to reuse existing code-base?

Tags: windows-phone-7, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, projects-and-solutions, windows-phone-8

Fist of all I want to say that I've read these two discussions:
[How to organize Windows Phone code base to target both 7.x and 8 platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799646/how-to-organize-windows-phone-code-base-to-target-both-7-x-and-8-platforms) and
[Windows Phone 7/WPF - Sharing a codebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522355/windows-phone-7-wpf-sharing-a-codebase). So, I know about Portable Class Librariy project type which might be an answer to my question. But it isn't an answer for my case.

### Problem

I have some old code-base in my project `WindowsClassLibraryNetFw35`. I need this project to be a class library which targets .NET Framework 3.5. The reason for it is that some dependent applications are deployed on customers' machines which don't have .NET Framework 4+ installed. Unfortunately I can't force my customers to upgrade their environment.

Now I create new project(s) for Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8. As you know, Windows Phone 8 projects will fail when I attempt to reference my old library because it is not a compatible Windows Phone project (see screenshot).
[image]

### Question

What is the best way to reorganize my project type(s) in order to be able to support both my old and new projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would still aim to get a PCL working, but if that fails, you can use the same code in two different projects.

Create two different projects, one Windows Phone, the other a Windows Store App. Add a file to one, then add that other file [*as a link*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306234) to the other project. This means you have a single source file between two different projects, but will be compiled with each respective runtime tools. Then you can do things like this in your code:

```
void Foo()
{
    #if WinRT
        //WinRT specific code here
    #elif WindowsPhone
        //Silverlight specific code here
    #endif
}
```

Just add the respective compiler constants on the Build tab of your Windows Phone and WinRT projects. This is far a more tacky solution, but sometimes its the only approach that works.

Comment: Thanks! Well this solution isn't new for me. The problem is that there is no easy way to introduce these files in every new project I create. It will take a lot of time to add these files, right? May be I could create a `*.csproj` template which will contain all the files from a library project(s). That approach also has a problem. If I add a new file to the library project, I need to add a link to it in every already existing client project and update the `csproj` template. What I'm trying to say that it seems to be a lot of rut boring actions which disturbing me from development process.

Comment: @keykeeper Unfortunately I think this is all there is. You may be able to develop a tool that aides this process, but the "solution" is use .NET 4.0 and PCL.

Comment: I CAN'T use PCL because some of my old projects target .NET Framework 3.5 and I can't force clients to update it to version 4.